# FontColor-Property for disabled Buttons?

Tags: smartface.io

Is there a Property in Smartface to set the Font-color of a Text-Button when it is disabled? With the following code, I would expect the Font-Color of the button would be red, but it is white. Color only changes to red, if I do not disable the button.

```
Pages.Pg_Pass.btn_stamp_3.enabled = false;
Pages.Pg_Pass.btn_stamp_3.fillColor = "#00FFFF";
Pages.Pg_Pass.btn_stamp_3.fontColor = "#FF0000";
```

Answer (score 0):

fontColor property should change regardless of the textButton's enabled property. I mean you should see the fontColor as red although enabled is set as true or false.

I think you are using an Android device. This is a known issue for Android and will be fixed soon.